# Linq Where clause not returning what I expect when performing String.Contains(String) on a null string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I scratched my head for one hour on this yesterday with no results but sweat.

```
string SearchTag = "";
Extension.getDBService<MyClass>().FindAll(i => <true condition>);
```

This returned me all my MyClass DB records as I would expect.

```
string SearchTag = "";
Extension.getDBService<MyClass>().FindAll(i => <true condition> && i.TAG.ToLower().Trim().Contains(SearchTag.ToLower().Trim()));
```

This returned a 0 Count collection!! I do not understand this.

```
string SearchTag = "e";
Extension.getDBService<MyClass>().FindAll(i => <true condition> && i.TAG.ToLower().Trim().Contains(SearchTag.ToLower().Trim()));
```

This returns a collection containing all MyClass DB records again. This is normal as i.TAG always contains "e".

Why do I get a 0 members collection with the second expression?
"string".Contains("") should always be true right?

PS: Extension.getDBService() is a call to a DBContext by the way.

Thx for your assistance.

Comment: remove <true condition> and give it a try

Comment: Are you sure `SearchTag` is an empty string and not a `null`? The two are very different (in SQL, `null` propagates through almost all operations by default, and is "falsy"). Make sure the code you're posting actually displays the behaviour you describe. But all in all, there's little reason for you to include the filter if it's supposed to filter nothing - just compose your query instead of putting it all in one `FindAll`, and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble :)

Comment: "string".Contains("") should always be true right? - i don't think so. its working as it should be since your searching for an empty string.

Comment: a work around for this is (SearchTag  == "" || i.TAG.ToLower().Trim().Contains(SearchTag.ToLower().Trim())).

Comment: You are using LINQ to Entities. All you write in the where clause must be translated to SQL by an algorithm. There is no such (standard) SQL like "contains" so you must expect some behavioral differences C# vs SQL. As a general advice: The less you write within the where clause, the less side effect you will get. So do for your SQL translator (and yourself) a favor: do not include the "SearchTag.ToLower().Trim()" in the where clause. Instead convert the argument _once_ outside the query. (btw: even without the unexpected issue this is a recommended practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, the way you wrote the LINQ query generates SQL `CHARINDEX(...) > 0` criteria which returns false for empty string.

However, if you remove (move outside the query) the `ToLower().Trim()` part of the `SearchTag` variable

```
SearchTag = SearchTag.ToLower().Trim();
```

and use

```
i.TAG.ToLower().Trim().Contains(SearchTag)
```

inside the LINQ query, then the generated SQL criteria is `LIKE` operator and works as expected.

Just another example that LINQ to Entities is not like LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Brillant finding Ivan. It is just as you said :) Thanks a lot.